# Transition a html-node to full screen regardless of initial position?

Tags: css

I have 9 floated items on the screen. creating a 9x9 grid.

```
.part {
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 33.333%;
    float: left;
}
```

Whenever I hover a `.part`, I wish to transition-resize trans the item so that it fills the entire screen, scaling from the initial position. Assuming I don't know the items initial possition, can this be done with pure CSS?

Comment: What would happen to the other divs?

Comment: As in the answer given not with floats...in fact I think positioning would be the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to archieve something like the following:

[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/hawcubite/pen/ZpGWKV)

So it is possible as long as you have the option to position the nine boxes absolutely.

```
.part {
  position: absolute;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 33.333%;
}
```

But I don't see any way to archieve this with floating boxes; this would just be against the principle of floats.